# I can't access the primary key in django?

Tags: python, django

I am sure I have made a rookie mistake somewhere down here.
So I have a details page for a particular link. Suppose I have list of incubators on my page, and if I click on one of them, I want to show its details. I am sure this can be done by using primary key but I keep getting errors.

**models.py**

```
class Incubators(models.Model):       
  # I have made all the required imports
    incubator_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city_location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.FileField()
    verify = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):                  # Displays the following  stuff when a query is made
      return self.incubator_name + '-' + self.owner 

class Details(models.Model):
    incubator = models.ForeignKey(Incubators, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    inc_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    inc_img = models.FileField()
    inc_details = models.TextField(max_length= 2500)
    inc_address = models.TextField(max_length = 600, default = "Address")
    inc_doc = models.FileField()
    inc_policy = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.inc_name
```

**views.py**

```
def details(request, incubator_id):
    inc = get_object_or_404(Incubators, pk = incubator_id)    
    return render(request, 'main/details.html', {'inc': inc})
```

This is my urls.py but I'm sure there's no error here:

```
url(r'^incubators/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', views.details, name = 'details'),
```

Can you explain a little why I am getting this error?

```
TypeError at /incubators/9

details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/incubators/9
Django Version:     1.11.3
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

Comment: _"can you explain a little why I am getting this error?"_ You haven't even included an error. How can you expect us to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your URL patterns, you're calling the variable "pk" but in your view you're calling it incubator_id

To fix this, change your URL pattern from:

```
url(r'^incubators/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', views.details, name = 'details'),
```

to

```
url(r'^incubators/(?P<incubator_id>[0-9]+)', views.details, name = 'details'),
```

Comment: @ArjunKashyap,  good that your issue is fixed, why don't you mark it as accepted answer. It helps someone with similar issue